# how do you rename a column in Excel that has word wrap applied to it using pandas

Tags: excel, pandas, dataframe

In Excel, wordwrap is applied to a column.  The column name is HomeroomTeacher on the top line and FirstName on the second line.

If I use `data.rename(columns={'HomeroomTeacherFirstName':'TeacherFN'}, inplace=True)` it doesn't change it.
If I use `data.rename(columns={'HomeroomTeacher FirstName':'TeacherFN'}, inplace=True)` it doesn't change it.

However, if I open the spreadsheet first and put my cursor at the end of HomeroomTeacher and hit the delete key once the new name HomeroomTeacherFirstname is changed to TeacherFN.

I don't want to have to touch the spreadsheet to do this.  Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Can you look up how python is reading the original column? Check the results of doing data.columns and see if is using a special character to represent the new line.

By default pandas rename does not raise an error if one of the columns in the dictionary is not in the table:

`DataFrame.rename(mapper=None, *, index=None, columns=None, axis=None, copy=None, inplace=False, level=None, errors='ignore'`)

The errors parameter is ignore by default which might not be ideal.

Comment: when I do for col in data.columns print(col)  it returns   SchoolCode
SchoolName
LastName
FirstName
MiddleName
Student Number
Grade
HomeroomTeacher
LastName
HomeroomTeacher
FirstName
SchoolCategory
CharterStatus as you can see no special characters.  As I said in the orignal post if I open the spreadsheet first and put my cursor at the end of HomeroomTeacher and hit the delete key it becomes HomeroomTeacherFirstName and I can rename that.  I just don't want to have to touch the spreadsheet at all

Comment: I tried to replicate your problem with an excel and a column written using wordwrap. My code looks like this: 

```import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_excel('test.xlsx')
print(df.columns)
df.rename(columns={'Column B with text wrap': 'RenamedB'}, inplace=True)
print(df.columns)
```

And the output shows that the columns is being changed:
```python test.py 
Index(['Column A', 'Column B with text wrap'], dtype='object')
Index(['Column A', 'RenamedB'], dtype='object')```
Sorry I can´t help you.

Comment: In excel, make a column label with word wrap turned on.  Then in pandas try to rename it to a single word label